# How to make a square with text inside using MigraDoc + PDFsharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm using the table class in unison with columns and cells to add data inside, being images or text but I have to draw something really weird I don't know how to replicate it using borders (if it is possible even).

It's the following:

[image]

So its a square, inside the square 2 paragraphs I would say horizontally centred.

My idea... the only one I can think of (but I don't know if it is the best solution) would be to make a table with N rows and each row a cell with left and right border except the first one and the last one where it will have top and bottom, then .AddParagraph() for the 1st and last cell.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be:

```
private static Table DibujarSelloYFirma(Section sec)
{
    Table table = new Table();

    Column column = table.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(3));

    Row row = table.AddRow();

    Cell cell = row.Cells[0];
    cell.AddParagraph("SEAL COMMERCE");

    cell.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
    cell.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
    cell.Format.Font.Bold = true;
    cell.Format.Font.Size = 3;
    cell.Format.Font.Name = "Verdana";
    cell.Format.Font.Italic = true;
    cell.Borders.Right.Width = 0.5;
    cell.Borders.Left.Width = 0.5;
    cell.Borders.Top.Width = 0.5;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Row rowEmpty = table.AddRow();
        cell = rowEmpty.Cells[0];
        cell = rowEmpty.Cells[0];
        cell.Borders.Right.Width = 0.5;
        cell.Borders.Left.Width = 0.5;
    }

    Row rowFinal = table.AddRow();
    cell = rowFinal.Cells[0];
    cell.AddParagraph("FIRMA");
    cell.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
    cell.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
    cell.Format.Font.Bold = true;
    cell.Format.Font.Size = 3;
    cell.Format.Font.Name = "Verdana";
    cell.Format.Font.Italic = true;
    cell.Borders.Right.Width = 0.5;
    cell.Borders.Left.Width = 0.5;
    cell.Borders.Bottom.Width = 0.5;


    return table;
}
```